# NGINX + mediawiki: Setting a index.html on top of index.php (index priority)

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, mediawiki

I am trying to set a index.html file to be on top of my mediawiki installation. I could set it to the logo link at the header but I am having trouble setting the domain to point to that index.html instead of the default index.php mediawiki comes with. On a Apache server I could easily set a .htaccess at mediawiki's root folder, but since I am using NGINX that doesn't work.

I tried to set a "index index.html index.php;" on a location block in the .conf file but it is not working.

Comment: why do you want to do that? What is the intended behavior then? What do you expect?

Comment: I just want to have a straightforward (and aesthetically pleasing) interface when the user lands on my wiki. Specially because at the moment there's not a lot of articles published so the mediawiki index is very empty. 
The intended behaviour is to use the search field first, similar to https://www.wikipedia.org/ - a main search field with some secondary links.

Comment: Ok, how does your current nginx configuration looks like? Usually it should work like you tried, at least from what you wrote.

Comment: Also, where have you placed the `index.html` file? Is it in the same folder as MediaWiki's `index.php` file?

Comment: Mediawiki root folder, same place as index.php.

Comment: I just followed the configuration on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/mediawiki/ and added the "index index.html index.php;" on the "location /" block

Answer (score 0):

There were nothing wrong with the directive I was using. However, the server running NGINX had another set of configurations for the same site in a different folder that I was unaware of. So if you are facing the same problem, double check the folder "sites-available" or any other folder under /etc/nginx/.